# registerShutdownHook() vs Closing an application vs. Application crash?

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning the spring framework for Java with web applications in mind. I'm ok with everything I've worked on so far but had a question.

When I create a new `ApplicationContext`:

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml")
```

Eclipse gives the warning, "Resource leak: context is never closed". but `ApplicationContext` has no `.close()` method. So after some quick research, I need to cast context to an object that does have it. No big deal.

Alongside casting context and calling `.close()`, I also found that calling `.registerShutdownHook()` also clears the warning. This got me wondering what this method actually does.

So my question is, what is the difference between `.registerShutdownHook()` and simply closing the application? Or between it and the application crashing? Some Googling gave the reply that it closed it, "Gracefully" - but what does that mean?

Comment: 'It gives the warning ...' 'It' being what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm working in Eclipse. It's not an error (it will let me run the application), just a warning. I updated the OP.